# How to configure the tsconfig.json file for an azure function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-functions

I have the following folder structure in my TypeScript project:

```
- azure_functions
  - function_app
    - functions
      - project_1
         function.json
         index.ts
      package.json
      package-lock.json
      tsconfig.json
      node_modules
```

This is the current configuration of my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "rootDir": "./",
  "allowJs": true,
  "strict": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noEmit": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "isolatedModules": true
},
"include": ["./**/*.ts"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

This is the configuration of my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "ts_project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && func start",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prestart": "npm run build && func extensions install",
    "start:host": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
},
 "dependencies": {
   "node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
},
 "devDependencies": {
   "@azure/functions": "^3.5.0",
   "@types/node-fetch": "2.6.2",
   "typescript": "^4.4.4"
    }
}
```

Whenever I run `npm start` I see that no conversion from TS to JS is performed and I end up with an error indicating that `Invalid script file name configuration. The scriptFile property is set to a file it doesn't exist.`

If I do a `tsc index.ts` inside of the project_1 folder, I will see my file converted to js. Why am I unable to perform the same through the package.json file?

What am I missing in my `tsconfig.json` file?

For reference, this is the content of my function.json:

```
{
"bindings": [
  {
    "authLevel": "function",
    "type": "httpTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "name": "req",
    "methods": [
      "get",
      "post"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "http",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "res"
  }
],
"scriptFile": "../dist/functions/project_1/index.js"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- Here I also faced the same error when I changed the `scriptFile` in the `function.json` they way you have written.
- Assuming that the entire function is in the `functions` folder. They you should not specify the `functions` name in the `scriptFile`  .
- The `scriptFile`   should be in this format

```
"../dist/project_1/index.js"
```

- Now you can run the `npm start` in the `functions` folder and it should start the function
  [image]

Comment: Did you add any additional config in the .tsconfig file? I am still getting the same error